# Angular changing button class css color by calling function issue

Tags: css, angular, typescript

In my angular code, I am trying to assign a css color to my button and need to call a ts function to return the css class name.

I tried the following code

```
<button style="height: 10%" class="getColor(days.date)">{{days.date}}</button>
```

In my ts code,

I have something like this

```
getColor(item: any) {


    return 'bg-green'; // define in my style.css
  }
```

I quickly noticed that class="getColor()" does not even call the function.

I thought about ngIf and ngTemplate but not sure if that will work. I using setting to 4 different colors as indicators like default gray, blue, red, and yellow.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `ngClass`

```
<button style="height: 10%" [ngClass]="getColor(days.date)">{{days.date}}</button>
```

[Repro](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qy2wrl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

Comment: I did not know about ngClass. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to call the function you need to use property binding like this

```
<button style="height: 10%" [class]="getColor(days.date)">{{days.date}}</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to toogle classes based on a condition you can use `ngClass`, like in the following example:

```
<div [ngClass]="{
   'example-class': condition;
   'another-class': getColor(days.date)
  }">
</div>
```

Or:

```
<div [example-class]="condition ? 'example-class' : 'other-class'"></div>
```